# Why does 'svn ignore' not ignore?

Tags: svn, ignore

I'm trying to add a Linux kernel to an SVN tree, which has a .git subdirectory - which I don't want to add.

Can anyone explain this behaviour - why does it NOT ignore the .git directory?

```
test2$ mkdir -p a/.git/blah
test2$ ls
a
test2$ svn propset svn:ignore .git .
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
test2$ svn propset -R svn:ignore .git .
property 'svn:ignore' set (recursively) on '.'
test2$ svn add a
A         a
A         a/.git
A         a/.git/blah
```

Answer (score 17):

The `svn:ignore` property on a directory lists the names in the *current* directory that will be ignored. You have set the `svn:ignore` property on your current directory to `.git`, but that does not apply to the subdirectory `a`. What you can do is first add `a` non-recursively:

```
svn add -N a
svn ci -m "add a directory"
```

Then set the `svn:ignore` property:

```
svn propset svn:ignore .git a
```

and then add your tree:

```
svn add a
```

This should ignore the `a/.git` directory.

Comment: The `commit` after the `add` is not really required. It's possible to add a property to a directory that is tracked in the working copy but not yet committed.

Answer (score 7):

The first `svn propset` sets the `svn:ignore` property on the **parent** directory of `a`.

The second `svn propset` does nothing, because `a` is not under SVN management yet.

Answer (score 5):

The `svn:ignore` property is for ignoring files in already added directories.

For avoiding the import of files (or directories), you should use the **global-ignores**-feature, which is configurable in file `~/.svn/config` (UNIX) or `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` (Windows) in the **[miscellany]** section.

Activate it by removing the `#` in front of the line:

```
global-ignores = .git
```

Comment: The problem with global-ignores is that the next guy to use the repo is *not* going to ignore the stuff you want to avoid seeing in the repo.

Comment: for this you can use a pre commit hook with a forced global ignore file